# Check iterator pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I want to know if the following check is necessary:

```
std::list<int> myList;
.....
for (std::list<int>::iterator itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); ++itr)
{
   if (itr != NULL) // Is This Check Necessary?
   {
      // DO SOMTHING.
   }    
}
```

I have seen this check in some places and I'm wondering if that is a necessary check.
Maybe this check is necessary if the list is an input to a function?

Thanks, 
Ofer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is an unnecessary check.
You might want to check `*itr != nullptr`, if the list held some kind of pointers.

Comment: In STL the iterator is set to the end iterator of a collection to indicate various negative return cases in functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessary. I am not sure it's even valid.

Comment: It's not, because `std::list::iterator` cannot be implemented as a pointer.

Comment: It's at the very least unportable, I'm not sure if implementations may allow this as an extension. @MichaelWild: True, but it might still be comparable with one, e.g. with `std::list::iterator::operator!=(void*)`

Comment: @MSalters I suppose an implementation would be allowed to do that. But what would it compare against? The link element?

Answer (score 1):

instead you can use new range based for loops (C++11), so you dont need to deal with iterator checking.

```
std::list<int> YourList;
for( auto z : YourList ) {
//
std::cout << z;        // z is int
// amazing codes and fun :)
//
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to check.If the myList is empty,then myList.begin() equals to myList.end()

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no way to test if an iterator is uninitialized, 
But you can initialize iterator to the end() of the container as a default value.

```
std::list<int>::iterator itr = yourlist.end();
//
if (itr != yourlist.end())
{
    //doSomething
}
```